# What Properties are available for purchase in Grand Theft Auto V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In GTA5:

- What properties are available for purchase?
- What is their income?
- What additional benefits do they offer (if any)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy the following properties in Grand Theft Auto V (note some properties can only be bought by certain characters). There are sometimes bonuses for owning properties, and almost all will ask for assistance from time to time (give you mini-missions).

## Any

**The Hen House** ($80,000)
$920 (87 weeks before profit)

**Sonar Collections Dock** ($250,000)
$23,000 per collection (11 collections before profit - 30 total)
$250,000 for collecting all 30 (total profit: 940,000)
Bonus: Unlocks "Death at Sea" mission

**Car Scrapyard** ($275,000)
$150 per car (1,834 tows before profit)

**Pitchers** ($750,000)
$7,100 (106 weeks before profit)

**Tequi-la-la** ($2,000,000)
$16,500 (122 weeks before profit)

**Los Santos Golf Club** ($150,000,000)
$264,500 (568 weeks before profit)
Free golf for all players.

## Trevor

**McKenzie Field Hangar** ($150,000)
$7,000 per air mission / $5,000 per ground mission
Bonus: Trevor gets the Cuban 800 and BF Injection vehicles.

**Vanilla Unicorn** (free with "Hang Ten" mission)
$5,000
Bonus: Trevor gets free lap dances and drinks. All characters can use hands.

## Franklin

**LSPD Auto Impound** ($150,000)
$500 per car (300 cars before profit)

**Downtown Cab Co.** ($200,000)
$2,000 (100 weeks before profit)
Bonus: Free taxi rides for Franklin

**Smoke on the Water** ($204,000)
$9,300 (22 weeks before profit)

**Los Santos Customs** ($349,000)
$1,600  (219 weeks before profit)
Bonus: Free custom upgrades for Franklin at the Route 68 location

## Michael

**Cinema Doppler** ($10,000,000)
$132,200 (76 weeks before profit)

**Ten Cent Theater** ($20,000,000)
$264,000 (76 weeks before profit)

**Tivoli Cinema** ($30,000,000)
$142,300 (211 weeks before profit)

## Franklin or Michael

**Hookies** ($600,000)
$4,700  (128 weeks before profit)

## Total Costs

The total money to buy everything in each of the categories above are:

ANY - $153,355,000
TREVOR ONLY - $150,000
FRANKLIN ONLY - $903,000
MICHAEL ONLY - $60,000,000
MICHAEL OR TREVOR - $600,000

TOTAL MONEY REQUIRED: $215,008,000

## Total Earnings

Once all the properties becomes profitable (max 568 weeks after purchasing them all), the total weekly profit is:

ANY - $289,020 (568 weeks)
TREVOR ONLY - $9700 (128 weeks)
FRANKLIN ONLY - $17,600 (219 weeks)
MICHAEL ONLY - $538,500 (211 weeks)

**NOTE: One week in GTAV equals five hours and 36 minutes in real life.**

Answer (score 4):

This IGN interactive map of Los Santos will show you where all 25 properties (and everything else) is located: http://www.ign.com/maps/gta-5/los-santos-blaine-county

[IGN also has a great list of all the properties](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Properties_You_Can_Buy), what they cost, who can access them, and how long it takes to payback the initial investment.

[image: IGN GTAV Property List]