# What properties come with a bonus besides the income they provide?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I recently found out that you can buy a garage (near Sandy Shores) with Franklin which gives you all car modifications for free. I was wondering what other properties come with an additional benefit besides the flat weekly income.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What Properties are available for purchase in Grand Theft Auto V?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132399/what-properties-are-available-for-purchase-in-grand-theft-auto-v)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. I think the title could use some work. It sounds like they mean what properties give you free stuff as opposed to just money.

Comment: @Reafexus Feel free to edit. English is not my native language and I don't understand where the title is misleading.

Comment: The title was very close to the question sommerjj links above but your explanation made it obvious they were different. You just want the title and explanation to be closer in meaning.

Answer (score 2):

as far as my knowledge goes there's a cab company you can own which let's you ride taxi's for free (so no real return on investment there unless you use the taxi service a lot)

Comment: Right, I remember. You get that one when you do the main mission, if not mistaken.